# Prevent Wireshark For Security Issue For Request A Get Method From URL Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, security, web, wireshark

If i send a request or open a url with codeigniter like this :

> https://abc.coms/controller1/data1/data2/data3

If anyone with the same network using a wireshark to capture the request HTTPS. Can wiresharks detect what we send ? Or can wiresharks see the exactly same what someone send or request ?

If yes, how to prevent it from being read by wiresharks.

Thank You

Comment: this might be of some help (my answer was misleading so I deleted it): https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/80991/can-someone-using-wireshark-obtain-the-full-url-if-my-program-uses-https

Comment: @Alex could you make it short for me ? I just want to know if when i send request : "https://abc.coms/controller1/data1/data2/data3" is it appear exactly the same in the wireshark traffic because i am using HTTPS

Comment: short: they can only possibly see the `abc.com` (domain) and the rest not (unless they have the private key and can decrypt the traffic with it)